# Minimization problem in a subset of Complex matrices

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I would like to minimize

$||\mathbf{A} \rho -v||$ (where $\rho , v$ are fixed vectors) with respect to the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ elements, **but** with $\mathbf{A}$ in a subset of complex matrices (i.e. $\det \mathbf{A}=0$). Is that possible in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Any code you wanna share with us ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is trivially solved using $$\mathbf{A}=\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}v\otimes\rho,$$
which automatically satisfies
$$\|\mathbf{A}\rho-v\|=0$$
and 
$$\det(\mathbf{A})=0.$$
In Mathematica, this is entered as `v\[TensorProduct]r/Norm[r]^2`.